# How to synchronize two scrollbars for divs with different style overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem trying sync scroll in divs, I have a two divs, the first div has a style with  overflow: hidden and the second div has the style with overflow:scroll,then i found a several answers for sync scroll in divs using jquery for example :

```
$("#div2").scroll(function () { 
    $("#div1").scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gqHyW/43/

but i have a problem with that solution because at the bottom of scroll the divs are desynchronized , see the image .

[image]

Someone has an idea how to solve this error.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your horizontal scroll is showing despite not needing to be there. You can target your horizontal scroll and hide it, while keeping your vertical scroll:

```
.bottom {
    left     : 50%;
    overflow-y : scroll;
    overflow-x : hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Radio thanks for your answer, sorry for the bad information in the image , the true is that, i need the horizontal scroll,I  updated the image and the  jsfiddle for show you my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/gqHyW/43/

Comment: Fastest way probably is to add a horizontal scrollbar to your left div too. Or a margin with the height of the scrollbar. But that is a mess since if I view it on a mac, the scrollbars would have different heights. Or else, a JavaScript handler for the left div scrolling wich syncs it with the right div and that if you go too far below, it takes it back up a little.

Answer (score 0):

My bad on my previous answer.

I see what you're after now.

You need to rifle through your P tags and sync the heights depending on the content heights in each.

Here's a function that ought to work in either direction:

```
var topPs = $(".top p");
var bottomPs = $(".bottom p");
for(var i=0; i< topPs.length;i++){
    var topPHeight = $(topPs[i]).height();
    var bottomPHeight = $(bottomPs[i]).height();
    console.log(bottomPHeight);
    if(bottomPHeight>topPHeight){
        $(topPs[i]).height(bottomPHeight);
    }else{
        $(bottomPs[i]).height(topPHeight);
    }
}
```

You still need the horizontal scroll fix I mentioned in my other answers.

I rolled it into a single fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/op9nddoq/1/

Edit: since this isn't a layout hack, it's perfectly acceptable to use a table here, as it's a table, and the cell heights will adjust all by themselves.